# react router won't serve me components other paths than '/'

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-router

Hi i added react router to my project but it wont serve me path others than '/'

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import store from './reducers'

import Header from './header/header'
import Toolbar from './toolbar/toolbar'
import Createprocess from './createprocess/createprocess'
import Hider from './createprocess/hider'

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}>
                  <Router>
                    <Route path='/module' component={Createprocess} />
                  </Router>
                </Provider>,
                document.getElementById('root')
              )
ReactDOM.render(<Header/>,document.getElementById('header'))
ReactDOM.render(<Toolbar/>,document.getElementById('tools-bar'))
```

this my createprocess component code :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'


import Actionsbar from './actionsbar'
import Processdisp from './processdisplay'
import DefineTask from './taskdefinition'
import store from '../reducers'

export default class Createprocess extends Component{
    render(){
        return  (<div id='create-process' className='default app-container'>
                    <Actionsbar/>
                    <Processdisp data={store.getState().processState}/>
                    <DefineTask/>
                </div>)
    }
}
```

when i add the module path i can't get it from my browser even if i used many combination

[image]

but the only time react renders is when i use th '/' path and i call my html page on the browser

[image]

i'm web designer i started webdevelopping recently and it seem that i can't get my head around those paths and serving pages, help please (i'm using babel/webpack).

Comment: PS: i'm using babel and webpack

Comment: Add additional information by editing your question and not in a comment.

Comment: What does your Createprocess component look like? Please add the code for Createprocess

Comment: That url looks very strange. When you use localhost:8080/module in the address bar, it goes to the localhost:8080/html/createProcess.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it seems that because there is no server serving pages i should have user HashRouter istead of BrowserRouter

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the route in a `Switch` component from react router

Comment: and using the history thing? because it's not working